# Обмен данными через Wi-fi с заданными параметрами в Android

Tags: android

Добрый день.

**Задача:** написать на Android  приложение, которое будет поднимать точку доступа Wi-Fi с заданными параметрами.

Потом к этой точке будет присоединяться устройство (самодельный считыватель чего-то), которое по `http` протоколу потоком передает информацию, которую и надо принять и положить в телефон(планшет) в какой-нибудь формат.

Буду очень признателен за любое напутствие, или помощь.
Всем всего хорошего.

При необходимости могу уточнить информацию

Comment: слишком размытый вопрос. вам надо для начала разбить его на более мелкие задачи и решать каждую отдельно. из очевидного: 1) включение точки доступа из приложение(скорей всего напрямую нельзя) 2) запуск сервера на андроид(точно можно)

Comment: Спасибо, Вы уже описали очевидные и я с этим согласен. Я первый раз на данном ресурсе, обещаю исправиться в дальнейшем.